# Shared Resource in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: vb.net, io, parallel.foreach

How do I control access to a shared resource in a Parallel.ForEach loop? I am trying to download multiple files in parallel, and I want to capture information about downloads that fail, so that the user can re-attempt the download later. However, I am worried that if more than one download fails at the same time, the application will throw an exception because one thread will attempt to access the file while it is being written to by another.

In the code below, I would like to know how to control access to the file at RepeateRequestPath. A RequestSet is a list of strings that represent IDs of the resource I am trying to download.

```
Dim DownloadCnt As Integer = 0
Dim ParallelOpts As New ParallelOptions()
ParallelOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
Parallel.ForEach(RequestSets, ParallelOpts, Sub(RequestSet)
        Try
            DownloadCnt += 1
            Dim XmlUrl As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=", String.Join(",", RequestSet), "&retmode=xml&rettype=abstract")
            DownloadFile(XmlUrl, String.Format("{0}\TempXML{1}.xml", XMLCacheDir, DownloadCnt))
        Catch ex As WebException
            Using Response As WebResponse = ex.Response
                Dim statCode As Integer = CInt(DirectCast(Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Failed to retrieve XML due to HTTP error {0}. Please hit the 'Retrieve XML' button to re-run retrieval after the current set is complete.", statCode))
                If Not File.Exists(RepeatRequestPath) Then
                    File.WriteAllLines(RepeatRequestPath, RequestSet)
                Else
                    File.AppendAllLines(RepeatRequestPath, RequestSet)
                End If
            End Using
        End Try
    End Sub)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to protect a shared resource in VB.NET is to use [`SyncLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t).

So, you would create a lock object before the `Parallel.ForEach()` loop:

```
Dim lock = New Object
```

and then you would use that inside the loop:

```
SyncLock lock
    File.AppendAllLines(RepeatRequestPath, RequestSet)
End SyncLock
```

Also note that you can use `AppendAllLines()` even if the file doesn't exist yet, so you don't have to check for that.

Comment: Perfect! Quick question, though. Can I use the same lock on a different file in the Try section of the Try-Catch block? Or do I have to instantiate a separate object? I want to do the same thing to another file after calling DownloadFile.

Comment: @user667118 You can. Another question is whether you should do that, because it would mean that if one thread wants to write to one file, it has to wait for another thread that writes to another file.

Comment: I think that won't be much of a problem because it doesn't take very long to write to the files. Overall, I'm still saving a lot of time because this code was previously running in a synchronous manner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a semaphore to control access to a shared resource.  You want only one thread to access the error file at one time, so initialize the semaphore to only allow 1 thread in.  Calling _pool.WaitOne should seize the semaphore, and then release it once it finishes creating/writing to the file.

```
Private Shared _pool As Semaphore
_pool = = New Semaphore(0, 1)

Dim DownloadCnt As Integer = 0
Dim ParallelOpts As New ParallelOptions()
ParallelOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
Parallel.ForEach(RequestSets, ParallelOpts, Sub(RequestSet)
        Try
            DownloadCnt += 1
            Dim XmlUrl As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=", String.Join(",", RequestSet), "&retmode=xml&rettype=abstract")
            DownloadFile(XmlUrl, String.Format("{0}\TempXML{1}.xml", XMLCacheDir, DownloadCnt))
        Catch ex As WebException
            Using Response As WebResponse = ex.Response
                Dim statCode As Integer = CInt(DirectCast(Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Failed to retrieve XML due to HTTP error {0}. Please hit the 'Retrieve XML' button to re-run retrieval after the current set is complete.", statCode))
                _pool.WaitOne()
                Try
                    If Not File.Exists(RepeatRequestPath) Then
                        File.WriteAllLines(RepeatRequestPath, RequestSet)
                    Else
                        File.AppendAllLines(RepeatRequestPath, RequestSet)
                    End If
                Catch ex as Exception
                    'Do some error handling here.
                Finally
                    _pool.Release()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Try
    End Sub)
```

Comment: Good point - Release wouldn't be called.  Not sure how acceptable a try catch block is in a catch block.

Comment: I chose to go with svick's solution because it's shorter, but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

svick's solution is almost right. However if you need to protect access to a shared variable you also need to declare your lock object as shared at class level.

This works correctly:

```
Friend Class SomeClass
    Private Shared _lock As New Object

    Private Shared sharedInt As Integer = 0

    Sub Main()
        SyncLock _lock
            sharedInt += 1
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you use a non-shared lock object, synclock will protect the variable only from multiple accessing threads within the same instance, not across instances.